# How to perform delta and sum functions in KroneckerProduct in Mathemtica?

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors

I am trying to simulate a tensors which includes sum and kroneckerdelta functions, `Sum[KroneckerDelta[b, d] gamma1[a, j] gamma2[j, c], {j, 1, n}]`. So I have used `Table` to create this as shown in following example:

```
n = 2
DHs = {{0.273896 + 0. I, 0.0967486 - 0.0561944 I}, {0.0967486 + 0.0561944 I,  0.0110102 + 0. I}}

U = {{-0.0654387 + 0.0871213 I, 0.596998 - 0.794809 I}, {0.994046 + 0. I, 0.10896 + 0. I}}

Ut = {{-0.0654387 - 0.0871213 I, 0.994046 + 0. I}, {0.596998 + 0.794809 I, 0.10896 + 0. I}}

gamma1[a_, b_] := Indexed[(Ut.DHs.U), {a, b}]

gamma2[c_, d_] := Indexed[(Ut.DHs.U), {c, d}]

Table[Sum[
   KroneckerDelta[b, d] gamma1[a, j] gamma2[j, c], {j, 1, n}], {a, 1, 
   n}, {b, 1, n}, {c, 1, n}, {d, 1, n}] // MatrixForm
```

I would like to perform same operation using  `KroneckerProduct`, as in actual problem the dimensions of the my matrices are very huge and I have to calculate many tensors and `Table` function is taking long time. So far, I have tried:

```
KroneckerProduct[Ut.DHs.U, Ut.DHs.U]
```

But, I am unable to use  `KroneckerDelta[b, d]` & `Sum[j,1,n]` on top of KroneckerProduct.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
B = Ut.H.U;
result = Transpose[
   ArrayReshape[
    KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray], B.B], {n, n, n, n}],
   {2, 1, 4, 3}
   ];
```

Comment: thankyou very much. Can you please explain little about ```{2,1,4,3}```  ? Rest I understand the math.

Comment: Well, the sparse 4-tensor generated by `ArrayReshape` has the correct entries but the slots are in a wrong order. `Transpose[...,{2, 1, 4, 3}]` this. Why `{2, 1, 4, 3}` specifically? Well, I _knew_ there must be a suitable transposition. So I tries just all of them and picked one that worked. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I got it.

Comment: Glad to hear that! You're welcome.